# Firefox does not display table-row as Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: css

Given the following code

HTML:

```
<div class="ci-v-stack-panel" style="width: 400px; height: 500px; border: 1px dashed green;">
    <div id="white" class="ci-v-panel">
        <div style="height: 50px">
            <span>content 0</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="red" class="ci-v-panel">
        <span>content 1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="green" class="ci-v-panel">
        <span>content 2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="blue" class="ci-v-panel auto">
        <span style="border: 1px dashed black;">content 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#white {
    background-color: white;
}

#red {
    background-color: red;
}

#green {
    background-color: green;
}

#blue {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

.ci-v-stack-panel {
    display: table;
    table-layout: auto;
}

.ci-v-panel {
    display: table-row;
    height: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.auto {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

I got the following results: 
[image]
Check it out on codepen: http://codepen.io/mcl7cdm/pen/BzjqQq

The last browser is Firefox.

What should I do in order to make it look the same in Firefox?

Comment: Try to set the last row to `height:100%`, and please remove all the `!important` it makes things *crazy!*.

Comment: @Pangloss Yepp, that works too :) ... and **yes yes yes** (remove `!important`)

Comment: Removing the "important" from auto breaks the expected result. The auto panels have to fill all the available space. If there are two auto panels, for example, the available space must be divided equally between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `height` a unit and a value bigger than 0

```
.ci-v-panel {
    display: table-row;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}
```